# Passing templated function into template function (Eigen Derived)

Tags: c++, eigen3

I have difficulties passing the static function of a templated class member to the other function. When I test in a non templated class, it is going well, but it gets an error when rewriting as a template. Here is the code.

ScalarEqs.hpp :

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

template<typename Real, typename Derived>
class ScalarEqs {
public:
    static Real linearAdvection(const Real &u);

    static Real dLinearAdvection(const Real &u);

    static Real sine(const Real &x, const Real  &y);

    static Real LxF(const Real &ul, const Real &ur, const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &a, Real (*fn)(const Real &),
                      Real (*gn)(const Real &), const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &norm);

};

template<typename Real, typename Derived>
Real ScalarEqs<Real, Derived>::linearAdvection(const Real &u) {
    return u;
}

template<typename Real, typename Derived>
Real ScalarEqs<Real, Derived>::dLinearAdvection(const Real &u) {
    return static_cast<Real>(1);
}

template<typename Real, typename Derived>
Real ScalarEqs<Real, Derived>::sine(const Real &x, const Real &y) {
    return std::sin((x + y));
}

template<typename Real, typename Derived>
Real ScalarEqs<Real, Derived>::LxF(const Real &ul, const Real &ur, const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &a, Real (*fn)(const Real &),
                                   Real (*gn)(const Real &), const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &norm) {

    return 0.5 * (Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>(fn(ul) + fn(ur), gn(ul) + gn(ur)) - a * (ur - ul)).dot(norm);
}
```

In main:

```
#include "ScalarEqs.hpp"

int main() {
    double ul = 2, ur = 2;
    Eigen::Vector2d norm, a;
    norm << -1, 0;
    a << 1,1;

    ScalarEqs<double, Eigen::Vector2d>::LxF(ul, ur, a, ScalarEqs<double, Eigen::Vector2d>::linearAdvection,
                                            ScalarEqs<double, Eigen::Vector2d>::linearAdvection, norm);


    return 0;
}
```

But the compiler returning an error:

```
    error: 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::MatrixBase(int, int) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>]' is private within this context
     return 0.5 * (Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>(fn(ul) + fn(ur), gn(ul) + gn(ur)) - a * (ur - ul)).dot(norm);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: declared protected here
 EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC ~Derived() = default;
                   ^
note: in expansion of macro 'EIGEN_DEFAULT_EMPTY_CONSTRUCTOR_AND_DESTRUCTOR'
     EIGEN_DEFAULT_EMPTY_CONSTRUCTOR_AND_DESTRUCTOR(MatrixBase)
```

Comment: That looks like a linker error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. How do you compile your program?
PS: I see another issue though. You are trying to use the `Eigen::Vector2d(double x, double y)` constructor via `MatrixBase`. I don't think this will work.

Comment: @M.A yes, I copy the wrong error message. I have edited to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

General hint to start: When encountering problems like that, try to reduce it to a minimal case.

To expand on my comment above: I don't see anything wrong with your code when it comes to templating / static.

E.g. This compiles and runs just fine with `g++ -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I/ScalarEqs.hpp main.cpp`

```
#include "ScalarEqs.hpp"

int main() {
    double d = 2;

    std::cout << ScalarEqs<double, Eigen::Vector2d>::linearAdvection(d) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I believe your function `LxF` has an issue however. You explicitely call a constructor `Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>(fn(ul) + fn(ur), gn(ul) + gn(ur))`. This constructor does not exist for MatrixBase and is specific to 2 dimensional fixed sized vectors.

If that is the only types of matrix types you need, you would need to update this function to

```
template<typename Real, typename Derived>
Real ScalarEqs<Real, Derived>::LxF(const Real &ul, const Real &ur, cons    t Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &a, Real (*fn)(const Real &), Real (*gn)(const Real &), const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &norm) {
  return 0.5 * (Eigen::Matrix<Real, 2, 1>(fn(ul) + fn(ur), gn(ul) + g    n(ur)) - a * (ur - ul)).dot(norm);
}
```

Comment: yeah, I also believe that the issue is in `LxF`, particularly how I define the function pointer `fn` and `gn`. Unfortunately, sometimes I need to pass an `Eigen::Vector2d` or an `Eigen::Vector3d` to the function.

Comment: Only those two types? Then the template parameter is just the length of the vector. Either way, if you need to pass individual elements to a constructor, you will need to specialize this function for N = 2, and N = 3 somehow, especially if you want to alter the number of input arguments as well for e.g. N = 3. Other approaches exist (e.g. variadic template params), but in this case a simple specialization would be more readable imho.

Comment: @Cendric let me try