# Specializing std::less for Eigen::DenseBase

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, template-specialization

I need a total order on both `Eigen::Matrix` and `Eigen::Array`, therefore I would like to specialize `std::less` for the parent class of both: `Eigen::DenseBase`. From https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html I know that I must define `std::less` for the templated type `Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>`. [Passing templated function into template function (Eigen Derived)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123133) contains a working example for the `Eigen::Matrix`, so I adapted that for the parent class and came up with

```
template <typename Derived>
struct std::less<Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>> {
    bool operator()(const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& lhs,
                    const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& rhs) const {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(),
                                            rhs.end());
    }
};
```

which does not work, because the compiler tries to use the default `std::less`, which uses `operator<`, which either does not exist (`Eigen::Matrix`) or does not return a single bool (`Eigen::Array`).

[How to define less than (<) operator or std::less struct for Eigen::Vector3f?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68321552) recommends not specializing `std::less` (when using a std::map), but to explicityly provide a custom compare struct, which works

```
struct eigenless {
    template <class Derived>
    bool operator()(Eigen::DenseBase<Derived> const& lhs,
                    Eigen::DenseBase<Derived> const& rhs) const {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(),
                                            rhs.end());
    }
};
```

My question: How can I make a specialization of std::less work with Eigen::DenseBase? Here's a minimal example: https://godbolt.org/z/jMdGzf7hT

Comment: Why specialize and not overload (or use the recommended structure)? What specific problem is the specialization supposed to solve that other ways can't?

Comment: first question, why would you need to specialize std::less? Generally you can make a custom comparator with the same signature and gives it as argument to stl algorithm that require such operator. Otherwise there might be an issue with name resolution. Look at how to specialize swap operations. I recall that it's well known and might be similar

Comment: I don't strictly *need* the std::less specialization and an explicit Compare works just fine. I want to understand, why the specialization does not work.

Comment: a hint: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap#:~:text=Linear%20in%20N-,Specializations,-std%3A%3Aswap%20may and a second one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130671/how-does-using-stdswap-enable-adl

Comment: hum: the technics describe in my previous comment does not seem to work. First less is a functor not a function, thus it seems that ADL cannot be triggered in the same way. Besides, I'm not sure that injecting ```less``` in the namespace where the map is handled is affecting the ``map``` ```operator[]```. Sorry for the wrong tracks. I hope that someone will give more precise information about what works and what does not (and why).

Comment: AFAIK, ADL is used in template parameter deduction whereas here, a struct is used which will be explicitely specialized. From there the rules are unclear (for me) about which partial specialization may be considered when injecting symbols from different namespaces.

Comment: You should not specialize in `std` for something you don't own (at least partially). You risk ODR violations (NDR) when library updates (if they add the specialization themselves). Custom compare struct is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: this is not a complete answer but it's too long for mere comments.

First issue is that the specialization of `less` is not in a `std` namespace or a namespace embedded into `std` so the specialization cannot be considered:
from [cppreferences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization)

> This declaration must be in the same namespace or, for member templates, class scope as the primary template definition which it specializes.

Second issue is that `Eigen::Array3d` inherits from `Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>` but is not `Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>`. Adding a specialization for `Eigen::Array3d` make it works as below, but its not what you want to achieve.

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <map>

namespace std {
template <class Derived>
struct less<Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>> {
    bool operator()(const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& lhs,
                    const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& rhs) const {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend(),
                                            rhs.cbegin(), rhs.cend());
    }
};
template <>
struct less<Eigen::Array3d> {
    bool operator()(const Eigen::Array3d& lhs,
                    const Eigen::Array3d& rhs) const {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend(),
                                            rhs.cbegin(), rhs.cend());
    }
};
}  // namespace std

// not specializing std::less, but using custom Compare, see
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68321552
struct eigenless {
    template <class Derived>
    bool operator()(Eigen::DenseBase<Derived> const& lhs,
                    Eigen::DenseBase<Derived> const& rhs) const {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(),
                                            rhs.end());
    }
};

int main() {
    Eigen::Array3d a;
    Eigen::Array3d b;
    auto map1 = std::map<decltype(a), int>();
    map1[a] = 1;
    map1[b] = 2;
    auto map2 = std::map<decltype(a), int, eigenless>();
    map2[a] = 1;
    map2[b] = 2;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/TTTqxdPb9)

In your case, extending std with partial specialization seems to be allowed:
[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std):

> **Adding template specializations**
> **Class templates**
> It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library class template to the namespace std only if the declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and the specialization satisfies all requirements for the original template, except where such specializations are prohibited.

By the way, specializing in an unrelated namespace [won't work](https://godbolt.org/z/5hWKdvxjq).

Regarding the inheritance issue, i'm beginning to think that it's not possible, at least without modifying the primary template parameters, which is not possible in this case.

In your case, you can yet specialize for `Eigen::Array` (and `Eigen::Matrix`):

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <map>

namespace std {
template <typename Scalar, int RowsAtCompileTime, int ColsAtCompileTime>
struct less<Eigen::Array<Scalar, RowsAtCompileTime, ColsAtCompileTime>> {
    bool operator()(
        const Eigen::Array<Scalar, RowsAtCompileTime, ColsAtCompileTime>& lhs,
        const Eigen::Array<Scalar, RowsAtCompileTime, ColsAtCompileTime>& rhs)
        const {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend(),
                                            rhs.cbegin(), rhs.cend());
    }
};
// template <>
// struct less<Eigen::Array3d> {
//     bool operator()(const Eigen::Array3d& lhs,
//                     const Eigen::Array3d& rhs) const {
//         return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend(),
//                                             rhs.cbegin(), rhs.cend());
//     }
// };
}  // namespace std

// not specializing std::less, but using custom Compare, see
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68321552
struct eigenless {
    template <class Derived>
    bool operator()(Eigen::DenseBase<Derived> const& lhs,
                    Eigen::DenseBase<Derived> const& rhs) const {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(),
                                            rhs.end());
    }
};

int main() {
    Eigen::Array3d a;
    Eigen::Array3d b;
    auto map1 = std::map<decltype(a), int>();
    map1[a] = 1;
    map1[b] = 2;
    auto map2 = std::map<decltype(a), int, eigenless>();
    map2[a] = 1;
    map2[b] = 2;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/PEfdMb3z4)

[EDIT] Eventually, a workaround is possible for the inheritance management, without modifying the primary template (which is not possible in this case). I don't find it satisfying but I give it anyway, for the record:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct EigenWrapper {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Eigen::DenseBase<T>, T>::value, "");
    using type = T;
    T const& val;
    EigenWrapper(T const& v) : val(v){};
};

namespace std {

/// works only for 1D data, that have iterators
template <typename T>
struct less<EigenWrapper<T>> {
    bool operator()(EigenWrapper<T> const& lhs,
                    EigenWrapper<T> const& rhs) const {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.val.cbegin(), lhs.val.cend(),
                                            rhs.val.cbegin(), rhs.val.cend());
    }
};

}  // namespace std

int main() {
    Eigen::Array3d a;
    Eigen::Array3d b;
    auto map1 = std::map<decltype(EigenWrapper(a)), int>();
    map1[EigenWrapper(a)] = 1;
    map1[EigenWrapper(b)] = 2;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/xzv8obd8T)
In this snippet, I create a kind of proxy class for all classes derived from `Eigen::DenseBase` and I partially specialize `std::less` for these proxy. As you can see, it is not sufficient to manage both arrays and 1D data because only 1D data have an iterator interface in `Eigen` it seems. But you can keep the same technic to specialize even more (`std::less` specialization for `EigenWrapper` can now delegate its implementation to a user-defined functor that can be specialized according to the nature of the wrapped object).
Yet in this case, its at least as much work as having a specialization for `Eigen::Array` and `Eigen::Matrix`. Besides client code is
less readable as it must work with `EigenWrapper` objects instead of *plain* ones. With C++ lesser than 17, situation would be even worse as the `EigenWrapper` template argument could not be deduced from constructor. You would have to explicit it or use a creator function to have argument deduction.
Nevertheless I found the technic worth mentioning because it can be applied to another class hierarchy.

Hope it will help.

Comment: thank you very much your answer! Question regarding the first issue: I can't see a difference between specializing `struct std::less` vs `namespace std { struct less ...` in the compiler behavior. The specialization for Matrix and Array work without opening a namespace but instead using a qualified id. What am I missing / misunderstanding?

Comment: removing ```namespace std``` fails as expected on my side: https://godbolt.org/z/KWxTrcKoe. What's your compiler? Your compilation options?

Comment: of course it fails if neither `std::` nor `namespace std {` is there, but I was wondering why in your examples you explicitly opened the `namespace std` instead of just using the qualified struct name `std::less` as in my minimal example. I understood your first remark as if it was necessary to open the namespace and qualifying `std::less` was not enough

Comment: Sorry I failed to find a reference stating that declaring a new specialization with a scope resolution name is the same as declaring it inside the namespace. A language-lawyer is needed there.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler doesn't understand that `Eigen::Array3d` is `Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>` when tries to compile your code. When you use `struct eigenless` it doesn't make sense, because `Eigen::Array3d` is convertable to `Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>`. If you want to use spezialized `std::less` , you could use something like this

```
template<>
template<typename _Scalar, int d>
struct std::less<Eigen::Array<_Scalar, d, 1>> {
    bool operator()(const Eigen::Array<_Scalar, d, 1>& lhs,
                    const Eigen::Array<_Scalar, d, 1>& rhs) const {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(),
                                           rhs.end());
    }
};
```